# How to test for multiple intersections in java?

Tags: java, jpanel, draw, game-physics, rectangles

I am currently making a tower defence game.

Simply put it works like this: green circles (enemies) move across the screen. By clicking, you can place a tower. The enemy has a rectangle hidden underneath it, and the tower has a large opaque rectangle around it indicating its hit range. If they are colliding, the enemy starts to lose health, until it dies.

Before, I used this test to see if the enemy was within range of the tower:

```
for(int i=0;i<enemy.length; i++) //Runs for the total amount of enemies
{
  for(int j=0; j<boxes.length;j++) //Runs for the total amount of towers placed
  {
    if(enemy[i].getEBox().intersects(boxes[j]))  //boxes[j] is the towers' range box
    {
      enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth()-1);
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like the towers to only be able to shoot one enemy at a time, most preferably the enemy at the front. To do this I need java to detect that there are multiple enemies colliding with the rectangle and only damage the front enemy.

Here is the test I ran to do this (The enemies array value go backwards so the first one to appear is enemy[0] and the last enemy[10] for example):

```
for(int i=1;i<enemy.length; i++) 
{
 for(int j=0; j<boxes.length;j++) 
  {
   if(enemy[i].getEBox().intersects(boxes[j])&&!(enemy[i-1].getEBox().intersects(boxes[j]))) 
    {
  enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth()-1);
    }
  }
}
```

however, the second condition always returns a positive. How can I change my if statement to conduct a successful test?

Comment: What happens when 2 collide at the same time?

Comment: You would have a conditional that keeps running till the first object that intersected is dead... then remove it from a list... then move on to the next object that was added second... then wait till its dead.... then remove it from the list... and so on.

Comment: It runs exactly the same as the first loop. The second condition always passes..

Comment: @DarkV1 But what if i have 2 towers and the first tower doesn't kill the enemy? That would leave the rest of the towers inactive until the first enemy is dead.

Comment: You would get the number of towers that the enemy is in range of. and subtract the enemy health based on the damage of the total amount of towers

Comment: @DarkV1 That already happens. If two towers are built very close with interlocking range boxes, then the enemy dies quicker, the only problem being that 2 enemies can be damaged simultaneously by one ower, rather than only one tower being able to damage one enemy. If you like you can check out the full program over here?: http://pastebin.com/4D3TSAFW You'll have to save each file to a folder.

Comment: hmm... well if the first two towers dont kill it fast enough ... then you remove those towers from the enemy as they are not in range anymore.... Then continue to check if the enemy intersects with any other towers... and add those to an array. repeat.... Not really sure where the problem is.

Comment: Oh i see what you are asking. one sec

Comment: @DarkV1 Removing them from the array would mean they stop moving though, so my problem is basically getting the enemy to not take damage if there is another enemy in front of it, also within tower range, without affecting the rest of the the program.

Comment: there is already a working solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a tower only shoot at one enemy, flip the loops and break the inner loop when shooting starts.

```
for(int j=0; j<boxes.length;j++) //Runs for the total amount of towers placed
{
  for(int i=0;i<enemy.length; i++) //Runs for the total amount of enemies
  {
    if(enemy[i].getEBox().intersects(boxes[j]))  //boxes[j] is the towers' range box
    {
      enemy[i].setHealth(enemy[i].getHealth()-1);
      break; // skip remaining enemies, since towers has used
             // up it's shooting capability for this round
    }
  }
}
```

If a tower can prioritize which enemy to shoot at, loop through all the enemies to find the best candidate, then shoot at it.

```
for (int j=0; j<boxes.length; j++) //Runs for the total amount of towers placed
{
   int enemyToShootIdx = -1;
   for (int i=0; i<enemy.length; i++) //Runs for the total amount of enemies
      if (enemy[i].getEBox().intersects(boxes[j]))  //boxes[j] is the towers' range box
         if (enemyToShootIdx == -1 || betterCandidate(boxes[j], enemy[i], enemy[enemyToShootIdx]))
            enemyToShootIdx = i;
   if (enemyToShootIdx != -1)
      enemy[enemyToShootIdx].setHealth(enemy[enemyToShootIdx].getHealth()-1);
}
```

Now you just have to implement the `betterCandidate()` method.

Comment: The top one is a bit buggy.. I haven't tried the bottom one, but the limited shooting isn't really how I aimed to do it and also, If towers overlap, or I draw more than a handful of towers, some towers don't actually harm the enemies at all..

Answer (score 0):

You could store the enemies in the order you detect them so you will know which is the closest. Like an ArrayList for detected enemies or an ID kind of variable for each enemy object, which initialized when detected. Im pretty sure there are a lot ways like this, so storing an order somehow could work. Once you have an order you can attack only that one and there is no need to test the detected objects anymore while still looking for coming enemies and keep storing them so on.
In your case

`if(enemy[i].getEBox().intersects(boxes[j])&&!(enemy[i- 1].getEBox().intersects(boxes[j])))`

I don't really see (or maybe just too tired) why you need these conditions to attack. If your array of enemies is already in order why dont you just attack the first? If inRange && isAlive if not you go on the next one. 
I hope i did not misunderstand anything and probably could help a bit. :)

Comment: The test is basically checking this:
is the enemy within range? &&  are there no enemies in front of it that are ALSO within range of the same tower? If so, deal damage. The only trouble with the ID idea is that it would mean I need to change how my enemy object class is layed out when I think I should be able to fix the problem with one iif statement.